# Open VBS in the same folder using VBA script

Tags: vba, vbscript

A word doc is in the same folder of number.vbs, and we want to open the vbs using macro of the word, we use the address of current folder and number.vbs instead of absolute address (because we might move the folder)

if using absolute address, the following code works

```
Sub AutoOpen()
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """C:\Users\yushuo\Desktop\doc sss test\number.vbs """, 1, True
End Sub
```

then I use the following to get and set address automatically and store in myWb, but doesn't work in CreateObject.run

```
Sub AutoOpen()

Dim wb As String
Dim myPath As String
Dim myWb As String

wb = "number.vbs"
myPath = ActiveDocument.Path
myWb = myPath & "\" & wb

'MsgBox myWb, 48

CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """myWb """, 1, True


End Sub
```

I also tried

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """myPath & " \ " & wb""", 1, True
```

still not working, also tried

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run myWb, 1, True
```

still not workng, any idea?

Comment: If your variable is between quotes it is interpreted as the string _myWB_ and not its value.

Comment: @Shrotter I tried Run myWb but doesn't work either

Comment: Try `myWB = """" & myPath & "\" & wb & """"` to creating the string.

Comment: @Shrotter That works great, I will post it as the solution

Answer (score 1):

We just need to set myWb as address instead of string, using

```
myWb = """" & myPath & "\" & wb & """"
```

so the complete code is

```
Sub AutoOpen()

Dim wb As String
Dim myPath As String
Dim myWb As String

wb = "number.vbs"
myPath = ActiveDocument.path
myWb = """" & myPath & "\" & wb & """"

' MsgBox myWb, 48

CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run myWb, 1, True


End Sub
```